# SHA1 checksum with K leading zeroes

Tags: c++, c, c++11, sha1, cryptocurrency

I am trying to find the super efficient way to generate an random string for the equation below:

```
checkSum = SHA1(fixed_string + random_string)
```

The checksum has to have k leading zero to satisfy the final condition. The current implementation is using brute force methodology combined with the **random string** generator. But this method is kind of inefficient and time consuming if the **K** is bigger than **7**.

```
static void
gen_random(char *s) {
    static const char alphanum[] =
        "0123456789"
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    for (size_t i = 0; i < LENGTH - 1; ++i) {
        s[i] = alphanum[rand() % (sizeof(alphanum) - 1)];
    }
}
```

Has anybody any idea to develop an efficient algorithm for generating random string to handle the condition in efficient way?
The Other question is about the length of **(fixed_string + random_string)**. What is the best length to handle the SHA1 check sum correctly?

Thanks

Comment: Cryptographic algorithms like SHA-1 are designed to be hard to reverse. Unless algorithmic weaknesses have been found, you should not expect to be able to improve much over brute force. You can use [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1#Attacks) as a starting point for known issues in SHA-1. The technical papers referenced may have applicable information, but you should expect they require considerable knowledge to apply.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, you trying here to validate SHA1 implementation.
For this, I suggest using test vectors from [NIST](https://csrc.nist.gov/Projects/Cryptographic-Algorithm-Validation-Program/Secure-Hashing#shavs)

There are test vectors for byte-oriented and bit-oriented implementations.

Example of a test vector from `shabytetestvectors/SHA1ShortMsg.rsp` file

```
Len = 152
Msg = 148de640f3c11591a6f8c5c48632c5fb79d3b7
MD = b47be2c64124fa9a124a887af9551a74354ca411
```